# How to compare text: ANSI vs Unicode

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find a certificate by serial number.
Apparently both sides are equal but debugger says they are not.
What am I missing here? I noticed IDE warned me when I copied & pasted
serial number into text editor, I didn't care about the message;
unicode blah blah...

**UPDATE**

1. I copied the serial number from certificate window.
2. Open Notepad2 new file. It's default ANSI. Pasted the text. Copied again. Pasted into VS. Values are not equal.
3. Set Notepad2 file as Unicode. Pasted serial number. Copied from Notepad2 and pasted into VS. Now they are equal.

It seems unicode vs ansi problem.

[image: serial.png]

Comment: Can't you post actual code rather than that horribly difficult-to-read bitmap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with how you create the string or how you compare it. That should work just fine. Strings in .NET are always unicode, so there is no possible encoding problem either.

Retype the serial string manually. It seems that you got some unusual characters in there when pasting it, for example non-breaking spaces instead of regular spaces.

Comment: I typed space by hand and then trimmed. No luck.

Comment: @NimeCloud: Try to retype the entire string, including the quotation marks. There might be a zero-width character in there somewhere which isn't visible at all. Unicode has a zero-width space for example.

Answer (score 2):

When I copied I've selected "extra space". Weird but it doesn't appear in the IDE. If I select the serial number carefully, everything will be ok.

In Notepad it appears as below:

```
?00 c4 aa b9 b1 08 90 5d
```

It's hex 3F char (question mark) and it doesn't appear in notepad if it's unicode. In ANSI mode it becomes visible as ?

[image: diff.png]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, comparison in UNICODE works flawlessly when English alphanumerics are used. For other languages, there are caveats.

Will you please provide "copy-able" code, so that I ca check it on my machine? (PS: I am feeling too lazy to type it..:o)

Also, note that == works only with value types. You should use EqualsTo() for comparing ref types (this way, you will be comparing values, not references!)

Comment: The `==` operator doesn't only work for value types, it works for types that implements it, and the `String` class does implement it.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of

```
operator==
```

you should use

```
string.Equals(object Obj)
```

method. The "==" tests for equality of the reference not contents.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx.aspx) for further reference.

Comment: That's incorrect! for string, it does not test the reference, it still tests the contents

Comment: Check [this](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html) out! Internally it refers to the Equals-method and apart from that is not as confusing as musing "==".

Comment: It is about my statement, that you should use string.Equals() instead of operator==.